# Neural Network in Python

Tags: python

I have recently began attempting to create my own neural network without any NW module like Tensor Flow, but I could not get a already defined var into a function, so I put the data into a text file then read and write to it. Although it would not let me turn my weights back to an int to so I can multiply them by their learning rates. I get an error saying something like the int doesn't work with the base.

[image]

If you guys have any tips for this, it would be greatly appreciated. (Keep in mind that I began attempting to create this after a day of studying machine learning and neural networks, but of course I know how to code)

Comment: In the future can you please post code and error messages as text not images? Thanks! It's probably clear enough this time though.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things, 
`readlines()` returns a list so you probably want to index into it or use `readline()` to get a single value.
If you value is the string '2.62' you want to either cast it to a float and work with a float or, if you realy want an int, cast it to a float then to an int or apply other logic to make it castable to a int as '2.62' is not directly castable to an int. Hope this helps.